# Is it possible to create log source health alerts in Azure Sentinel?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-sentinel

I am attempting to create an alert that lets me know if a data source stops providing logs to Sentinel. While I know it displays anomalies in log data on the dash board, I am hoping to receive alerts if a source stops providing logs for an extended period of time.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like creating a rule with the following query (CEF in this case):

```
    CommonSecurityLog
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(24h)
    | summarize count() by DeviceVendor, DeviceProduct, DeviceName, DeviceExternalID
    | where count_ == 0
```